# Understanding the Skorohod-space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am having a lack of understanding the Skorohod space considering cadlag processes.

A random variable $X$ is measurable  mapping between two measure spaces  say $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})\mapsto (\tilde{\Omega},\tilde{\mathcal{F}})$.

I am struggeling about the primary space and the state space in terms of the Skorohod space, when we are considering cadlag-processes. This may be trivial, but i hope you can help me out.

Lets say we have a cadlag-process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$. How can we describe the mapping in terms of the Skorohod space $D(T,\mathbb{R}^{k})$, which is defined by consisting all cadlag paths from $T$ to $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, where $T:=[0,\infty)$
We denote by $\mathcal{B}_T$ the corresponding $\sigma$-algebra ,

So can we  relate $D([0,\infty)\mathbb{R}^{k}$ to $\Omega$ or $\tilde{\Omega}$? 
An what does terms of the canonical presentation $X(t,\omega)=\omega(t)$ change?

My attempt:

Generally we have a given probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and a cadlag process $X=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ defined on it. For every $\omega \in \Omega$ the mapping $X(\omega)$ defined by
$$
X(\omega): T\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k}\\
t\rightarrow X_t(\omega)
$$
is an element of $D(T,\mathbb{R}^{k})$. So we can see $X$ as the mapping 
$$
X:\Omega \mapsto D(T,\mathbb{R}^{k})
$$
This mapping is $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{B}_T)$ measurable. We denote $Q:=P^{X}$ as the by $X$ induced measure on $(D(T,\mathbb{R}^{k}),\mathcal{B}_T)$.

So for every $\mathbb{R}^{k}$-valued cadlag-process $X$, we can refer the Skorohod space, as the statespace of $X$.

However  $X$ can be seen as the equivalent process of $\pi:=(\pi_t)_{t\geq 0}$ on $(D(T,\mathbb{R}^{k}),\mathcal{B}_T)$; the coordinate process $\pi_t(\omega)=\omega_t$ for $\omega \in  D(T,\mathbb{R}^{k})$
so that
$$
\pi:(D(T,\mathbb{R}^{k}),\mathcal{B}_T)\mapsto (D(T,\mathbb{R}^{k}),\mathcal{B}_T)
$$
Let $Q^{\pi}$ be the induced measure of $\pi$. Then
on $((D(T,\mathbb{R}^{k}),\mathcal{B}_T,Q)$ it holds $Q^{\pi}=Q=P^{X}$ as defined above. So we can always identify a cadlag process as a random variable on the Skorohod space.

So we can use both representations

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, Skorohod works with $\Omega$ being the Skorohod space.
Then canonical projection $X$ is $X_t(\omega) = \omega(t)$

You see càdlàg processes as random variables on the skorohod space. You just care about law.

That is very useful to prove existence in law of processes defined as limit of processes.

Comment: i updated my question with your hint. Can you take a look at it. And i can mark this post as done. Best regards

Comment: Yes. You completely explain the two visions. Think now about strong and weak existence of solution of SDE. Strong is the existence of the mapping X. Weak existence is the existence of $P^X$. Hope it is a good example.

Comment: Ok thanks. This is nice to hear.  How do your hint (considering solutions of SDE), expand the understanding of this problem? I can't figure out at the moment. I thought by the two visions i explained, it doesn't matter, which "vision" one takes. The stochastic based on the two "visions" is the same. Or does it matter?

Comment: Yes. $dX_t=sg (X_t) dB_t $ has a weak sense but not a strong sense.

Comment: But how can this bee seen as a criterion that we have to differ between $X$ defined by my first mapping and $\pi$ as my second mapping.?